# Can i use Modernizr on my Phonegap ios app?

Tags: ios, cordova, modernizr

I'm just playing with an app i'm making, but i just wanted to know if it's ok to use Modernizr for my ios app using Phonegap. My reason being that i need to find a way to handle what resolution images to serve, and someone suggested Modernizr has a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I think Modernizr would be some kind of "Oversized" (1.), but as plain JavaScript library you can deliver it in your www-folder.

If you simply want to load different images for different screensizes you may also use css-mediaqueries.

1. Oversized, because you can be sure, you have a modern (webkit based) browser. 
   You have a geolocation API and you won't need IE polifils.